# Movie where monster transforms into people's desires

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to remember the name of this movie where a monster would transform into people's desires in order to kill them.

A few scenes I can remember are:

- The monster transforms into a girl in order to seduce one of the guys.
- At the end of the movie they escape on a boat but the monster was on it because that was their desire.

Comment: Do you know when you saw this? Was it new at the time? What language was it in?

Comment: Hi there! :) That's some info already, but  it might be worth to take a look at [this guide for story-ID questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories to [edit] in. For instance, when did you watch that? was it in English, was it a translation? If you watched that on TV, any ideas which channels it could have aired on? Stuff like that, to increase the chances of a successful identification. Cheers!

Comment: For what it's worth, a [rejected edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/132209) added the following info, provided the anonymous user was the OP: `I saw this movie around 2008 or 2009 and it was in English on tv.`